# What does a "-all" do in an included (secondary) SPF record?

Tags: spf

In an SPF record, the `-all` option means “I am whitelisting just the machines/domains I am explicitly listing here, and no other servers can originate email for this domain.”

So what does it mean when one uses the `include:` option in an SPF record to include a second SPF record, and that **secondary** SPF record has `-all`? What is the effect of it being there?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of adding a concrete example to clarify the question. It should help remove any perceived ambiguity.

Comment: @DanielB Except you changed the question to something other than what I asked.  Reverting.

Comment: I apologize, but I don’t see how the example is not exactly what you asked about. Examples help illustrate what you’re asking about.

Comment: @DanielB because he is "Codeswitcher" by name, what do you expect then? :) Codeswitcher, please don't see it as a asking for a fight again, it just a joke that usually helps to resolve even more complicated stuff. You asking interesting question but it lacks of information and correct terms.

Comment: Almost the same question with a **very well explaining answer**: [SPF with -all includes directive with ~all?](https://serverfault.com/q/848711/84914)

Answer (score 4):

The include mechanism will trigger a recursive evaluation for the included record. If this evaluation fails (e.g. by a -all in the included record), the result of the include mechanism will be considered a "Not match". So in practice a -all mechanism (or any other mechanism with - qualifier) in an included SPF record does not have any effect on the evaluation of the primary record.

A full overview of how the include mechanism affects the evaluation of the primary record can be seen in the table in section 5.2 of RFC 7208 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2)

Comment: Ones again, there NO such term in SPF as a "secondary record" !

Comment: "Secondary record" was the term used by OP, so I just answered using the same term. As I read the question, "secondary record" refers to the included SPF record.

Comment: Do not forget that bunch of lurkers may assume that it is Ok to use multiple SPF  records in DNS.    Included != secondary.

Comment: I have edited the answer to reduce the risk of terminology confusion.

Comment: Thanks for understanding. I dealing with such issues (secondary - multiple SPF records in DNS ) on daily basis that's why I trying to make accent on that

Answer (score 4):

For an SPF check to pass, the sending IP address must pass at least one of the mechanisms. Include mechanisms test the incoming IP address using the included SPF record and 'return' the result.

Using your example:

```
a.example.com    IN TXT "v=spf1 include:b.example.com +all"
b.example.com    IN TXT "v=spf1 -all"
```

The included record will return fail, since it only contains a `-all` mechanism. However, the first record will pass because it has a `+all` mechanism.

Using a more detailed example:

```
a.example.com            IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 mx include:spf.example.org -all"
a.example.com            IN MX  0 mailserver.example.com
mailserver.example.com   IN A   1.2.3.5
spf.example.org          IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:4.3.0.0/16 -all"
```

I will write down the result of each mechanism in the same order they are specified in the record. So, the results will be formatted as such:

- a.example.com: `[ip4] [mx] [include] [-all]`
- spf.example.org: `[ip4] [-all]`

With the following sender addresses:

**1.2.3.4**

- spf.example.org -> `fail fail`
- a.example.com -> `pass fail fail fail`

The final result will be `pass`, since at least one check passed

**1.2.3.5**

- spf.example.org -> `fail fail`
- a.example.com -> `fail pass fail fail`

The final result will be `pass`, since at least one check passed

**4.3.10.20**

- spf.example.org -> `pass fail`
- a.example.com -> `fail fail pass fail`

The final result will be `pass`, since at least one check passed

**TL;DR:** The include mechanism is evaluated separately and the result passed back to the evaluation of the record that included it. Record evaluation fails if no mechanisms match. Since you ended your example with `+all`, it will always match and therefore pass.

Answer (score 0):

The `-all` at the end is interpreted after any includes are handled.

Its purpose is to communicate how emails not sent through the listed resources should be treated.

`-all` means drop them as forgeries while `~all` means they might still be legitimate and should be treated with more suspicion.

Comment: I think you wanted to say - "`-all` means that this outgoing server is authorized to send email and all other  must be dropped as forgeries", otherwise one need to list almost the whole internet

Comment: That's what he said. "how emails not sent though the listed resources should be treated"